# Netty channelActive vs channelRead0

Tags: netty

I am using netty 4.0.33 to build a SSL/TLS client/server. For every connection, I want to log a message that TLS connection is successful between the 2 peers.
Where should I put this code snippet? channelActive or channelRead0? I am a bit confused about the purpose of channelActive and channelRead0. Looks like on the server side, we don't need channelActive at all. Is that true?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something when the handshake is successful you can use:

`class MyHandler extends ChannelInboundHandler {
    @Override
    public void userEventTriggered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object evt) {
        if (evt == SslHandshakeCompletionEvent.SUCCESS) {
            // Your handling logging
        } else {
            super.userEventTriggered(ctx, evt);
        }
    }
}`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The goal I am trying to achieve is, if the SSL connection is successful then log it. If the client just completes the TCP handshake, and does not initiate SSL, then log it too.

Answer (score 0):

You can add LoggingHandler to your pipeline and it will log if client is active. Active means connected. ChannelRead is called after channelActive and here you can read messages. In channelActive you can initialize some helpful stuff if you need (e.g. add connected channel to queue).