# What is the difference between channelActive and channelRead in netty?

Tags: java, netty

Does any  one  know 
what is  the  difference   between  channelActive  and  channelRead    in netty?

I am learning netty by reading the Netty User Guide (https://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-4.x.html)

I have tried to write an echo server and the following is my inbound `ChannelHandler`.

I have started my echo server, and when I try to telnet my server using its IP address and port there is no output apart from the message: "Lost connection to host machine"

When I debug my code, I find that execution gets into  the method `channelActive` but not into `channelRead`.

I want to know  what is  the  difference   between `channelActive`  and  `channelRead` in netty, and why execution gets into `channelActive`.

The following is my `ChannelHandler`

```
package com.yjz.middleware.netty;

import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelFuture;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelFutureListener;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter;
import io.netty.util.CharsetUtil;
import io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil;
import io.netty.util.ReferenceCounted;

import java.nio.Buffer;

public class DiscardServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
  @Override
  public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    ByteBuf in = (ByteBuf) msg;
    System.out.print(in.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
    ctx.write(msg);
    ctx.flush();
  }

  @Override
  public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
    // Close the connection when an exception is raised.
    cause.printStackTrace();
    ctx.close();
  }

  @Override
  public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    final ByteBuf time = ctx.alloc().buffer(4);
    time.writeInt((int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L + 2208988800L));
    final ChannelFuture f = ctx.writeAndFlush(time);
    f.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
      @Override
      public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
        assert f == future;
        ctx.close();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43151405/netty-channelactive-vs-channelread0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that `channelActive(...)` is called once the channel became active (which for TCP means the Channel is connected) and `channelRead(...)` is called once you receive a message.

As you use close the Channel directly in the `ChannelFutureListener` that is used in `channelActive(...)` your `channelRead(...)` is never called.

Comment: I knew from the beginning that you might answer me，thank you. i think got it ,I'm your fan in china